# React Context: Provide instance of an Api Manager

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, redux-persist

I want to keep a single instance of a third party api manager class in my react app.

I'm trying to achieve this using using the React Context Api like this:

**Api Context**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { ApiManager } from "../ApiManager";

const defaultValue = new ApiManager()

const ApiContext = React.createContext(defaultValue);
const ApiProvider = ApiContext.Provider;
const ApiConsumer = ApiContext.Consumer;


const withApi = (enhanced) => {
    return (
        <ApiConsumer>
            {api => enhanced }
        </ApiConsumer>
    )
}

export default ApiContext;
export {ApiContext, ApiProvider, ApiConsumer, withApi};
```

in my client I would do something like this:

const api = new ApiManager({
    host: apiHost,
    baseUrl: apiBaseUrl,
    key: apKey,
    sessionToken: persistedSessionToken
});

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<h1>loading...</h1>} persistor={persistor}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <ApiProvider value={api}>
                    <Main />
                </ApiProvider>>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Does this even make sense?
2. How would I set the sessionToken if it gets renewed by the user?
3. How do I rehydrate the api instance after a page reload using `redux-persist`?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want to use one instance of `ApiManager` then I don't think you need Context API. Just create an instance and export/import it in files where you need it.
2. You can wrap that third party api manager to add some methods you need like `setSessionToken` to set/update `sessionToken` when app loads or when user receives/refreshes it.
3. Why bother with `redux-presist` in this case (even if you decide to use Context API) if Redux is not involved. If you want to store `sessionToken` so store it in `localStorage` or any other storage you want, it has simple API to set/retrieve values, you don't need to use a library for it.